# Getting admin privilages and keep them in C#

Tags: c#, windows, security, admin

Is it possible that my program asks only first time starting it for admin privilages and when starting it again it has already admin privilages?

Kind regards

Comment: Possible? Probably. A good idea? Probably not

Comment: Whether programs needing to run as an administrator require a prompt from the user is a setting that the  *user* sets for them, not a setting your program sets for itself.  If the *user* wants to be prompted before running any program as an admin, that's the behavior they'll get.  If they don't want to be prompted, they won't be.  Trust your users to remove the prompt of that's the behavior they want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. However, as said by Biesi Grr, it's not a good idea, for logical questions. It is not sure that people will write a harmless code, and asking for admin privileges is the very reason for this: if something that drastically changes the environment you're working is asked to be done, you should decide about it every time (and not just say "hey, do what you want, I don't care".